Find dataframe row where a column's datetime value matches another column's datetime value and return a value from the matching row
I am trying to find the row where a column 'c2' datetime value matches another column 'c1' datetime value  and return a value from the matching row 'rtn' as a 'new' value. It works with the following example
In the actual problem the second date column contains an the date an earlier predicted value for the date. There are a number of these predictions made at date-1d, date-2d etc . What I want to produce eventually is a graph comparing the final value with all the future predicted values.
from datetime import  datetime#, timedelta #, date # 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': [10, 11, 12], 'date2': [12, 11, 10],  'rtn':[21,22,23],'new':[99,99,99]})

print(df['date1'].isin(df['date2']) )
print(f'date1 \n{df.date1 == df.date2}')

datatypes = df.dtypes
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['new']=df.loc[df['date2'] ==row['date1'],'rtn'].iloc[0]        

datatypes = df.dtypes
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

However when I use datetime dates as opposed to integers it does not (I have included commented out attempts converting the datetime to string, float and even int as above and it fails)
from datetime import  datetime#, timedelta #, date # 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_time_ref = datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=00, minute=00, second=00)
date_time_date11 = datetime(year=2024, month=10, day=20, hour=1, minute=00, second=00)
date_time_date12 = datetime(year=2024, month=10, day=21, hour=13, minute=00, second=00)
date_time_date13 = datetime(year=2024, month=10, day=22, hour=1, minute=00, second=00)
date_time_date23 = date_time_date11  #this is to ensure the test dates are identical 
date_time_date22 = date_time_date12  #this is to ensure the test dates are identical 
date_time_date21 = date_time_date13  #this is to ensure the test dates are identical 

print(f'Test {date_time_date11 == date_time_date21}')
print(f'Test {date_time_date11 == date_time_date23}')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': [date_time_date11, date_time_date12, date_time_date13], 'date2': [date_time_date21, date_time_date22, date_time_date23],  'rtn':[21,22,23],'new':[99,99,99]})


datatypes = df.dtypes
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['new']=df.loc[df['date2'] ==row['date1'],'rtn'].iloc[0]        

datatypes = df.dtypes
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

print(df['date1'].isin(df['date2']) )
print(f'date1 \n{df.date1 == df.date2}')

I have tried the following conversions to datetime above without any change to the result
df = df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows

# 1. convert to strings for comparison
df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H') #':%M:%S')
df['date2'] = df['date2'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H') #:%M:%S')

# 2. convert the datetime column to an ordinal
df['date1'].apply(lambda x:x.toordinal())
df['date2'].apply(lambda x:x.toordinal())

# 3. convert the datetime column to an integer divide the resulting integer by the number of    nanoseconds in a second
df['date1'] = df['date1'].astype(int)/ 10**9
df['date2'] = df['date2'].astype(int)/ 10**9

# 4. convert datetime to seconds
pd.to_timedelta(df.date1).dt.total_seconds()
pd.to_timedelta(df.date2).dt.total_seconds()

# 5. convert datetime to float64
df['date1'] = df['date1'] - date_time_ref
df['date2'] = df['date2'] - date_time_ref
df['date1'] = df['date1'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
df['date2'] = df['date2'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

# 6. convert to float64 above to int64
df['date1'] = df['date1'].astype(np.int64)
df['date2'] = df['date2'].astype(np.int64)

The values of 'new' should be 23, 22 21 as when the initial code is run. But when the inputs date1 and date2 values are changed from type 'int' to type 'datetime' the code no longer gives the correct output.
Why the same code works for one type of input (int) and not the other input type (datetime) mystifies me.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, what's the question exactly? It seems like you're asking why the code works for ints but not datetimes, but it's not clear what "works" means. Please show the desired output and undesired output. See [ask] for tips like how to write a good title then [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

You can assign the new column by mapping on a subset of the dataframe.
In the below, we map the date1 column to a pandas.Series with date2 as the index and the first rtn for each date2 value as the value.
df["new"] = df["date1"].map(
    df
    .drop_duplicates("date2")
    .set_index("date2")
    ["rtn"]
).fillna(99)  # if you want a value of `99` where there is no match

This works for me on both the integers and timestamps.
